# Clicking on "spread" RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have RecyclerView in my layout with "0dp" width and "spead" width constraint. It works good, but if I don't have enough elements to fill the whole width, the recyclerView's onClickListener is not called when clicking on "empty zone".

How can I intercept a click on the empty part of this view?
When I am setting it to normal layout with "match_parent" width everything is ok.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvThumbnails"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_message"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:visibility="@{notification.sendit.files.size() > 0 &amp;&amp; notification.type != NotificationType.GROUPED ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it with changing "layout_width" to "match_parent" and removing width constraint.

If someone has a nicer solution, please offer. I will accept an answer which uses constraints.